# Sum of square roots of natural numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Recently, I've encountered the following question:

Assume that $n_{1}, \ldots, n_{k}$ are (not necessary distinct) natural numbers. If

$$ (\sum_{i = 1}^{k}\sqrt{n_{i}}) \in \mathbb{N},$$ can we conclude that all $n_{i}$'s are perfect squares? Is there any famous theorem that answer this question? Or, can anyone introduce some references to help me know about this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have searched a bit [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%20%3D%201%7D%5E%7Bk%7D%5Csqrt%7Bn_%7Bi%7D%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Arational&p=1). (I was less successful [with SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B%5Csum_%7Bi+%3D+1%7D%5E%7Bk%7D%5Csqrt%7Bn_%7Bi%7D%7D+%5Cin+%5Cmathbb+Q%7D%24&page=1&tm=0&domains=).)  You can find various posts which are closely related (and could be considered as an answer).

Comment: AoPS: [rational numbers](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1534567p9248841),
[math.se]: [The sum of square roots of non-perfect squares is never integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/437350#437374).
The answer (and references) given here might be of interest, too: [The square roots of different primes are linearly independent over the field of rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30687)

Comment: Please don't close this question as the answer given by Random is nice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let us show a more general statement, and then show how it implies your question: given distinct positive squarefree numbers $n_1, n_2, \dots, n_k$, the numbers $\sqrt{n_1}, \dots, \sqrt{n_k}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Proof: Suppose that
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{k} a_i \sqrt{n_i} = 0$$
where without loss of generality, $a_1 \neq 0$. Dividing by $\sqrt{n_1}$ we get
$$a_1 + \sum_{i = 2}^{k} a_i \sqrt{\frac{n_i}{n_1}} = 0$$
Take the trace of this algebraic number with respect to the field extension $\mathbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{\frac{n_2}{n_1}}, \dots, \sqrt{\frac{n_k}{n_1}} \right) / \mathbb{Q}$. On the one hand, it should be 0. On the other hand, for all $i \neq 1$, the trace of $\sqrt{\frac{n_i}{n_1}}$ is 0 as it as a multiple of the trace of this number with respect to the field extension $\mathbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{\frac{n_i}{n_1}} \right) / \mathbb{Q}$, and of course the trace of $a_1$ is some nonzero multiple of $a_1$, which is a contradiction.

In fact, I believe that this argument works even if we take $\sqrt[m_i]{n_i}$, where $m_i \geq 2$ are some positive integers.

---

Now to the question: for $1 \leq i \leq k$ write $n_i = r_i s_{i}^2$ where $r_i$ is squarefree. Then we have
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{k} \sqrt{n_i} = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} s_i \sqrt{r_i}$$
Combining terms with the same $r_i$, if not all $n_i$'s are perfect squares (that is equivalently, some $r_i$ is nonzero), then if this number is rational then we have a nontrivial linear combination of $1$ and some square roots of distinct squarefree positive integers, which as we showed above is a contradiction.

Comment: This would be much simpler if you didn't try to prove the more general statement - assume $n=\sum\sqrt{n_i}$ and let $k$ be the degree of the extension we are taking trace over. Traces give $\sum tr(\sqrt{n_i})=kn=k\sum\sqrt{n_i}$, and $tr(\sqrt{n_i})$ is either $0$ or $k\sqrt{n_i}$ depending on if $n_i$ is a square. To get equality, all $n_i$ must thus be squares.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I think that the general statement is quite nice in and of itself.